# Ubuntu stuck during boot with /dev/sda3 clean message

Tags: boot, 18.04

When I try to turn on my computer, the Ubuntu boot is stuck on a black screen with the message "/dev/sda3 clean message ..."
You need to know that I have a dual boot and before that my computer needed several minutes to turn on with Ubuntu. So I tried a systemd-analyze and found out it was because network.service.
Following several forums I did many changes :

- sudo systemctl edit networking.service than put [Service] TimeoutStartSec=10sec in it
- sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces and change all "auto" to "allow-hotplug"
- sudo systemctl edit apt-daily.timer and put : [Timer]
  OnBootSec=15min
  OnUnitActiveSec=1d
  AccuracySec=1h
  RandomizedDelaySec=30min
- sudo gedit /etc/systemd/system.conf and removing the "#" before DefaultTimeoutStartSec=10s  and
  DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s

I know that this wasn't smart to try all these and after that I think I stopped my Ubuntu to boot.
Hopefully after trying to start with recovery menu and restarting I am sometimes able to start my computer so I did the following boot info :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GHK2xqrC4Z/

If someone could help me it would be wonderful thank you