# Ubuntu doesn´t boot, gets stuck at "/dev/sda3: clean, ..." message

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have seen some similar questions but no answer works for me. The problem seems similar to this unanswered question [Ubuntu stuck during boot with /dev/sda3 clean message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249773/ubuntu-stuck-during-boot-with-dev-sda3-clean-message) but my version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

I also saw this question with my same problem [Error on Ubuntu boot up - "recovering journal"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924170/error-on-ubuntu-boot-up-recovering-journal). I did all the steps that the answer gives but it won´t work ("sudo fsck -f /" gave me the mounting error that is mentioned but I did "sudo fsck -nf /" and I got the 5 pass steps that are mentioned). After rebooting i have the same problem and it doesn´t boot.

It might be important: im working on a Virtual Machine, VMWare to be precise and this problem began after accidentally using all the memory I assigned to it.

I have some important work on the Virtual Machine so help is much appreciated.

Comment: You do have backups? You will have to boot a live installer chroot into system and do some housecleaning. Or can you boot recovery mode to just a terminal? If UEFI, press escape right after vendor logo, but before grub menu would normally appear to get a grub menu & boot second line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)